Is there a limit to the number of concurrent ICE/STUN/TURN requests in Chromium?
We are establishing audio-only WebRTC calls.
By changing only one variable, the number of concurrent WebRTC calls we establish at once, I can see a reliable failure to get RTP audio on the calls that are "last" in the batch.
So calls 1-3 all get Audio OK, but the fourth fails to negoitate audio. We have DTX detection on the server and are able to terminate these calls that are not producing any RTP audio, but we can't explain why.
Due to the consistent nature it feels like we're hitting a defined limit in Chromium. It must therefore be the case that each call connected is performing multiple STUN requests (One for each network adapter found?). And by connecting >3 calls we max out the concurrent STUN requests.
We can see in webrtc-internals for these calls which are not negotiated correctly, they do not show a bold local/remote candidate pair. And there are no stat graphs, because there is no RTP.
Other than hanging up and trying again, what can we do about this? Is there a way through the RTCPeerConnection interface or a limit in Chrome://flags we can adjust?
Our desire is to have at least 8 concurrent webrtc calls at once, up to 50-60 calls total.
Things tried:

STUN vs. TURN
Local vs hosted STUN service
Our STUN service vs. Google stun service
Increasing iceCheckingTimeout. With >=3 concurrent calls, it doesn't matter how high we set this, they always reliably fail to get audio
When N=8 all calls fail to get audio.


does the webrtc-internals candidate grid show candidate pairs? Do requests sent increase on those?

@PhilippHancke No the grids are empty for these bad connections. I also agree the posted reply is a LLM fabrication. I've gotten similar results myself.

you will probably need to do some wiresharking in parallel to see whether the requests get sent on the ports indicated (assuming the local/remote port pairs are formed)
This used to work but full mesh style has generally falled out of favor even for four participants

https://jsfiddle.net/6m0gpb1a/ does work at least

The issue with concurrent WebRTC calls in Chromium is likely related to internal limits on ICE/STUN/TURN handling. Based on your findings, it appears that exceeding three concurrent calls leads to failures in audio negotiation due to missing RTP streams. This could result from resource limitations or Chromium’s handling of multiple ICE candidates.
To address this:
1.  Use a TURN server instead of relying solely on STUN. TURN servers relay media traffic and can handle NAT traversal more reliably. Test both hosted solutions (e.g., Google’s TURN service) and custom setups to determine the best fit.
2.  Adjust your WebRTC configuration:
•   Increase iceCandidatePoolSize to optimize candidate allocation.
•   Set the iceTransportPolicy to prioritize relay candidates and reduce the dependency on local candidates.
3.  Explore Chromium settings via chrome://flags. Enabling flags like experimental QUIC protocol support may improve connection handling under high concurrency. While no documented ICE/STUN limit exists, tweaking these settings can help.
4.  Reduce active network adapters to minimize STUN requests. Chromium may generate multiple requests for each adapter, so disabling unused adapters (e.g., Wi-Fi if on Ethernet) could help.
5.  Increase iceCheckingTimeout to allow more time for connection negotiation. Use chrome://webrtc-internals to debug failed calls and verify ICE candidate pair formation.
If the issue persists with 8+ calls, it could be a Chromium-specific limit or bug. For scaling up to 50-60 calls, consider using an SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) or MCU (Multipoint Control Unit) to manage connections centrally, as this offloads negotiation and media handling from individual clients.
If none of these steps work, consider filing a detailed bug report to Chromium developers with reproducible steps and logs from webrtc-internals.

this sounds like written by a LLM ...
